Improving convergence rate of krylov schur iterations?
I am trying to implement krylov schur iterations. I am noticing that although my implementation converges, it does so really, really slowly. For a 40x40 matrix it is taking hundreds of iterations to reach a projection error less than 0.001.
Overview

Use arnoldi iterations to obtain a small hessenberg matrix from the input matrix an to generate the krylov matrix

Put the Matrix into it's schur form

Compute a sorting matrix that reorders the schur form from smallest to largest eigenvalue

Update the krylov matrix with the sorting matrix and the schur orthognal matrix

If converged, stop other wise repeat for a deflated subset of the problem.


The algorithm is made from multiple other algorithms, so let me describe the ones I have detected have a problem.
QR iterations
Base on the literature I am trying to use QR iterations with deflation and with wilkinson's shift (described here).
The general algorithm is:
A_1 = A; O_1 = I
converged_count = 0
while converged_count < dimension
   alpha = wilkinson_shift_coeff(A_i)
   (Q, R) = QR_decomposition(A_i - alpha * I)
   O_{i+1} = O_i * Q
   A_{i+1} = R * Q 

   converged_count = all consecutive columns of $A_{i+1}$ which have converged so far
  
  /* reduce the matrices to the unconverged columns */
  O_{i+1} = O_{i+1}[0..rows; converged_count..cols] 
  A_{i+1} = A_{i+1}[converged_count..rows, converged_count..cols]
  

I have also tried the naive QR iterations, QR with only shifts and QR with only deflation. In all cases I am getting really high iteration counts, for example for a 50x50 hessenberg matrix computed from a 400x400 sparse matrix, I am getting about 3k iterations mos tof the time and once I am getting oscillating behaviour where the matrix does not converge.
My toy input for the overall krylov schur implemntation is a diagonal matrix with ascending number from 1 to the dimension. i.e. the non zeros are a diagonal equal to 1, 2, 3 ..., n (where n=400).
This is producing a 50x50 hessenberg matrix which  is given to the QR method. I have verified the input is always a hessenberg matrix. I am unsure why it takes so many iterations to converge to 0.001 levels of precision.
This is the implementation of the QR algorithm I am using atm:
pub fn qr_iterations_with_shift_in_place(
    h: &mut faer::Mat<f64>,
    q_res: &mut faer::Mat<f64>,
    tolerance: f64,
) {
    fn has_converged(matrix: &faer::Mat<f64>, tolerance: f64) -> usize {
        for i in 1..matrix.nrows() {
            // Check only elements below the diagonal
            if matrix[(i, i - 1)].abs() > tolerance {
                // println!("{}", matrix[(i, j)]);
                return i; // Found an element below the diagonal larger
                          // than tolerance
            }
        }

        matrix.nrows() - 1 // All elements below the diagonal are within tolerance
    }

    *q_res = faer::Mat::identity(h.nrows(), h.ncols());

    let mut dbg = 0;
    let n = h.nrows();
    let mut converged_count = 0;
    loop {
        let mut active_h =
            h.submatrix_mut(0, 0, n - converged_count, n - converged_count);

        dbg += 1;
        let alpha = wilkinson_shift_coeff(&active_h.as_ref());
        let id = faer::Mat::<f64>::identity(active_h.nrows(), active_h.ncols());

        // Don't know why I need to negate it. It doesn't converge otherwise.
        let shift = -alpha * id;
        let qr = (&active_h - &shift).qr();
        let q = qr.compute_q();
        let r = qr.compute_r();

        active_h.as_mut().copy_from((r * q.as_ref()) + shift);

        let mut active_q_res = q_res.submatrix_mut(
            0,
            converged_count,
            q_res.nrows(),
            q_res.nrows() - converged_count,
        );
        active_q_res.copy_from(&active_q_res * q);

        converged_count = has_converged(h, tolerance);
        if converged_count == h.nrows() - 1 {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("qr iterations {}", dbg);
}
// page 6:
// https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/75282/18-335j-fall-2006/contents/lecture-notes/lec16.pdf
fn wilkinson_shift_coeff(mat: &faer::MatRef<f64>) -> f64 {
    debug_assert!(mat.ncols() == mat.nrows());
    let n = mat.nrows() - 1;
    let a = mat[(n - 1, n - 1)];
    let b = mat[(n, n - 1)];
    let c = mat[(n, n)];
    let delta = (a - c) / 2.;

    let mu = c - b * b * delta.signum() / (delta.abs() + (b * b + delta * delta).sqrt());

    mu
}


It would be very useful if you could show us a mathematical description of the problem you are solving, along with the algorithm (rather than its implementation) you are using.

As emntioned, I am trying to implement the krylov schur method, a high level description can be found here:
https://slepc.upv.es/documentation/reports/str9.pdf
The problem I am encountering is that the iterative process through which vectors move towards the eigenvectors is very slow.

I don't know the "Krylov Schur method". There are many Krylov methods, so this statement is not useful, and it's unlikely that your readers here will want to follow a random link to a PDF file somewhere on the internet just to find out.

@WolfgangBangerth the Krylov Schur method is the state of the art way of getting eigenvalues from large sparse systems. It is a generalization of the Lanczos method. E.g. arpack uses a special case of the krylov schur method in its implementation, the eigen solver for the julia language also uses the krylov schur method.

Can you edit the post to describe mathematically what you are doing as well as some description of what sort of behavior you expect to see for a problem of this type?

@whpowell96 I tried re-writing the question to focus more on one of the points in the algorithm which seems to be missfuncitoning.
